# Play2-Auth vs SecureSocial vs Deadbolt2

Tags: scala, spring-security, playframework-2.0, securesocial, deadbolt-2

I am using Play2 with scala. I am new in Play2 and scala. I need authentication and authorization in a project. So which is the best for me from following? And why?

1. Play2-Auth
2. SecureSocial
3. Deadbolt2

Is any one like a Spring security?
I need authorization based on a user role and also need social login like google+, facebook and twitter and also our own side login.

So please tell me the best solution for me. And also explain why it best?

Comment: James Roper (Tech lead play) mentions here (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/pobbEu-dduY/tJT_BnpHQy8J) that there is inclination towards Deadbolt2 to be included in play in future. So +1 to deadbolt2

Comment: I was about to ask this question myself.

Comment: There's also Silhouette. It's got nearly 400 commits on github and it looks like it's very actively mantained.

Comment: (On Silhouette's project page, it is called an *Authentication* framework - not sure whether that means it doesn't do authorization as well)

Comment: [play-pac4](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4) should also be part of the conversation. I've used it to add Google authentication to a web site but don't know how it compares to these others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deadbolt2 is only an Authorization framework. Play2-Auth and SecureSocial both do Authentication and Authorization but their Authorization capabilities are much weaker than Deadbolt2. Play2-Auth does not have social login capabilities (that I know of). SecureSocial does.

I am using SecureSocial for the exact use case you are mentioning: social and local logins with role-based authorization. It works well for my purposes. I am using the current stable version (2.1.4 for Play 2.2.x) but be advised that the next version (that supports Play 2.3.x) is quite different and the upgrade procedure is painful. I have tried it once and have given up on it for the time being.

Comment: Any idea if there are docs or a tutorial somewhere for the forthcoming 3.0 version?

Comment: Not that I know of. There is a high-level overview of the new 3.0 features here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/securesocial/AEnf2McpQXY/JQV85uRKBQwJ but no tutorial.